# What are the risks of using LMS on an Experience Cloud Site, and is it on the Roadmap to be GA?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-message-service, experience-cloud

Currently I have a few components that use the Lightning Message Service, but I realize that this feature is in beta for Experience Builder sites.  As of right now, my components seem to work as expected and required.

So, I have two questions:

- Are the risks of LMS support in Experience Cloud being in beta great enough where I should change my components so they use the pubsub module instead?
- Is LMS going GA for Experience Cloud on the roadmap (or even documented) anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Only SF can confirm this. Safe Harbor explicitly mentions not to rely on pilot or beta features, they may or may not make it.

Comment: Hey @manjit5190 - I actually did get a response from someone at Salesforce - see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a [response](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/0D54S00000A6n5y) over in the Experience Cloud Trailblazer group from Zachary Hawtof from Salesforce:

> as far as LMS functionality is concerned we feel very comfortable with saying it's fully functional in Experience Builder sites. Safe harbor we plan to put the GA tag on it in Winter, but we don't foresee any risk with using it today.

This satisfies my needs and I leave this here for anyone else.

EDIT: Per the [Winter 22 Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_experiences_lms_ga.htm&type=5&release=234), LMS for Experience Builder sites is set to be GA.

Comment: It good that this is official response. We recently were using a functionality which is going to be stopped in July so we are finding alternatives. It was in pilot.